# Affinity propagation comments

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

I was looking into affinity propagation for my similarity matrix problem and thought it would fit well. However, browsing literature I found [this comment](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/319/5864/726.3) that basically breaks both legs of affinity propagation.

Is AP considered a good approach or rather a failure?

Comment: You can also try http://micans.org/mcl - mcl is an older method that is conceptually similar (using exchange and reinforcement) but uses (sparse) matrix algebraic operations. It is widely used in bioinformatics. Disclaimer: I created it.

Answer (score 2):

There also is a followup / rebuttal to that comment...

It's linked at the original site, in "TECHNICAL COMMENTS":

> **Response to Comment on "Clustering by Passing Messages Between Data Points"**
> Brendan J. Frey and Delbert Dueck

If you went to the original site instead of spammy ResearchGate, you would have seen it cross referenced. Roughly this comment says that for larger data sets, AP works faster and yields better results in their experiments.

Other than that: try it out. Every data set is different, and there is no one-size-fits-all clustering algorithm. There are hundreds, because *none* is the ultimate clustering algorithm.